# Parse Migrated server image-links not working

Tags: android, parse-platform

I know the Parse service is now shut down. But we are already started and working with our own parse migrated server. For now i noticed an issue with image-links were not working. The below one is the example for image-link
http://files.parsetfss.com/2b92c952-8d2f-45e3-be54-0f7a98471f93/tfss-ea110144-f0a0-41d9-a815-afc755a1106a-PenitentialService.jpg 
You guys suggestions are really helpful for me.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you did on your migration. But you needed to migrate your Parse existing files too.

1. Get all files across all classes in a Parse database.
2. Print file URLs to console OR transfer to S3, GCS, or filesystem.
3. Rename files so that Parse Server no longer detects that they are hosted by Parse.
4. Update MongoDB with new file names.

You can refer to the the parse-files-utils module. https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-files-utils

This however will not be available now. I would suggest you contact them quickly at: migration@parse.com.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Cliffordwh